How to run u-boot shell command from kernel image written in c?
I'm creating standalone application for u-boot that is run as a os kernel image. I need to do some setup on custom hardware and after I'm done I would like to set some u-boot env variables. In u-boot shell this can be done with setenv command. For now, I would like to have a generic function to which I will pass the command as a string.
I have tried int system(const char *command) from <stdlib.h> but it did not work:
system("echo \"Hello world!\"");


"I need to do some setup on custom hardware and after I'm done I would like to set some u-boot env variables - Your requirement is vague. Is this "setup" code in U-Boot or the "standalone application"? To which copy of the U-Boot "environment" do you expect to "save" these variables? FYI there's the saved environment in some NV storage, but there's also the runtime environment. The U-Boot command setenv only affects the runtime environment, i.e. while U-Boot is executing. Is that what you really want to achieve? Is this an XY problem?

I would prefer to run my standalone application and then return to the u-boot shell which would load the appropriate OS. My application needs to be able to set which OS to boot (and optionally read a file from disk)

U-Boot provides a UEFI implementation. Why don't you write an EFI application and set Boot#### and BootOrder as needed? This way your application will be portable to other firmware.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@Xypron Does it include a compilation of U-Boot itself? Because I don't have access to that. I cannot change U-Boot in any way, that does not include the U-Boot interactive shell, because I have access to that. I have looked at the implementation of the syscall function in the U-Boot source code and I might try to use it because this code will not be run on any other architecture than Xilinx Arm Zynq 7000.

have you tried using the exec family of functions?

@CaptSiro UEFI is an API, part of which is implemented by U-Boot (if built with CONFIG_EFI_LOADER=y, which is the default). You don't have to recompile U-Boot to run an EFI binary.
